# Write Textbox to TextFile C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write information to a TextFile through TextBoxes (TextFile in this case is something like a database). It's working when I use `File.AppendAllText` in the Form, but I'm trying to make it happen through Methods.

I created a method called `AddClient()`

```
Client getClient = new Client();
public void AddClient()
{
    string client = getClient.FirstName + "," + getClient.LastName + "\r\n";
    File.AppendAllText(textFilePath, client);
}
```

And the Register button in the Form is called `RegisterButton` and contains :

```
ClientRepository getMethods = new ClientRepository();
Client getClient = new Client();
private void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getClient.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
    getClient.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
    getMethods.AddClient();
}
```

FirstName and LastName ofc are properties of `public class Client`

After the button click, they both get null values.
Help please ?

Comment: In `getMethods`, where is `getClient` set? Can you post the code showing it's declaration *and* where it's set?

Comment: @RB. beat me to it, i think it has to do with the sets being set up incorrectly

Comment: Seems to me that you should be passing getClient to AddClient() not sure where that other getClient above the AddClient() method is from...

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass the instance of the Client class that has the firstName and lastName correctly set from the input textboxes to the AddClient method, instead you create a new instance of a Client class inside the ClientRepository class, and, of course, this new instance has nothing in its properties.

Change your code to pass the instance of Client created in your form

in ClientRepository class

```
public void AddClient(Client clientToAdd)
{
    string client = clientToAdd.FirstName + "," + clientToAdd.LastName + "\r\n";
    File.AppendAllText(textFilePath, client);
}
```

in your form code

```
ClientRepository getMethods = new ClientRepository();
Client clientToAdd = new Client();
....
private void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clientToAdd.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
    clientToAdd.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
    getMethods.AddClient(clientToAdd);
}
```